# Click image to call php function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I need to click an image and it should run some php script that sets a php variable and reloads the same page.

I know it sounds simple but i've tried every different way I can think of and i'm guessing it's just something basic i've missed.

I've tried onclick of the image, a href and a onclick, making the image the 'submit button' of a form etc..

Any response would be appreciated.

```
<a href="#" class='lang'><img src="/images/flags/it.png" alt="it_IT" /></a>
<a href="#" class='lang'><img src="/images/flags/fr.png" alt="fr_FR" /></a>
```

I want the image alt value to pass it,
How it is possible please give some idea..

Comment: We can't help much without your code.

Comment: well what is the href you used?

Comment: Did you tried `$_GET`?

Comment: hi I'm new in this forum , i update my query, Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Lets say that the PHP variable you want to change is `$my_var`:

Set it like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['VarValue']) And !empty($_GET['VarValue'])){
//if it is passed and not empty store it
$my_var = $_GET['VarValue'];
}
else{ die(''); }//else don't let them display the page.
```

In the image put an `On Click Listener` hat call this function `PHP_var();`

In JavaScript add this function:

```
function PHP_var(){
location = "?VarValue=The_Value_That_You_Want_To_Set";
}
```

And the URL must be like this when you first call this page(lets say it is http://www.example.com/script.php?VarValue=The_First_Valeu_Of_Variable).

The function will change the VarValue value and will reload the page

Answer (score 0):

Use onclick="ajaxFunctionName()" to call an ajax function which executes your script

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="ajaxFunctionName()" class='lang'><img src="/images/flags/it.png" alt="it_IT"/></a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="ajaxFunctionName()" class='lang'><img src="/images/flags/fr.png" alt="fr_FR"/></a>

function ajaxFunctionName() {
    $.post({
      var lang = $( this ).children('img').attr('alt');
      url: "script.php?lang="+lang
    }).done(function() {
      // do something
    });
}
```

or

```
<img class='lang' src="/images/flags/it.png" alt="it_IT"/>

$('.lang').click(function(){
    $.post({
      var lang = $( this ).attr('alt');
      url: "script.php?lang="+lang
    }).done(function() {
      // do something
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $('.lang img').on('click',function(){
    var lang = $(this).attr('alt');
    var postdata = 'lang='+lang;

    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:postdata,
            url:'process/yourscript.php',
            success:function(data){
                // more processing here
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```